# root access side effects

Tags: android, testing

I want to test my app and I have a device with root access to test on.

Can I be confident the the behavoir of the app is not affected by the root access?

If it is affected are the specific areas of behavoir in which root access may cause different/unexpected behavior?

Is there a way to retrieve files (logs, test results) from a device without root access?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFIAK there really aren't any APIs that require root permissions. Apps that require root permissions execute system commands using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandStringHere);`

If you try to execute commands that you don't have permissions to run then the execution will fail. To get around the permissions problem you can execute the commands as `root` using `su`.

So if you aren't doing any of this you app should run exactly the same on rooted and non-rooted phones.

Comment: I have now a device without root access and su command does not work on it... is it possible to use su in such device?

Comment: Unrooted phones don't have the `su` binary because any phone with the `su` binary is rooted (by definition).

Comment: I solved the access issues on unrooted device by copying the files needed to a more accessable location (sd card)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you App doesn't require root access it does not have any sideaffects
You can see the log via `adb logcat` or the Logcat-View in Eclipse (with Installed ADT).
Also you can use JUnit Tests on Android.

Answer (score 0):

If your application asks and uses root permissions, then the application won't work in unrooted devices. Assuming that you don't need any root access, there is no difference between an application running in rooted or unrooted device. You can also test in emulator to see the differences if they exist.